# Xamarin.Forms WebView: e.Cancel = true in Navigating event is not working on Android when using custom WebViewRenderer

Tags: xamarin.forms, webview, xamarin.android, webviewclient

I want to redirect opened URLs to an external browser in my `WebView`, so I hooked its `Navigated` event:

```
webView.Navigating += (s, e) =>
{
    if (IsExternalUrl(e.Url))
    {
        try
        {
            var uri = new Uri(e.Url);
            Device.OpenUri(uri);        // show external links in external browser
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
            
        e.Cancel = true;   // <- not having any effects on Android
    }
};
```

Under Android, this leads to the URL being opened on Chrome and in the WebView at the same time. On iOS `e.Cancel = true` does work as expected.

I searched extensively on the web but found nothing that helped me, including this Xamarin forum thread: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/144314/using-webviewrenderer-and-webviewclient-causes-cancel-navigation-not-working

I now have a workaround, using the back navigation:

XAML:

```
<local:HybridWebView x:Name="webView" CanGoBack="True"  WidthRequest="1000" HeightRequest="1000" />
```

Code behind:

```
webView.Navigated += (s, e) =>
{
    if (e.Result == WebNavigationResult.Success)
    {
        if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)  // on Android, prohibit webview from mirroring urls 
            if (IsExternalUrl(e.Url))                  // that are shown on external browser
                webView.GoBack();                      // this is necessary because e.Cancel = true doesn't 
    }                                                  // work in webView.Navigating() event
};
```

Note: Initially, the Navigated event wasn't firing, so I pimped my `HybridWebView` with a `WebViewClient` featuring this override:

```
public override void OnPageFinished(Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url)
{
    RaisePageFinishedEvent(url, view.Title);

    ...
    ...

    var source = new UrlWebViewSource { Url = url };
    var args = new WebNavigatedEventArgs(WebNavigationEvent.NewPage, source, url, WebNavigationResult.Success);
    _renderer.ElementController.SendNavigated(args);
}
```

I'm currently using Xamarin.Forms 4.5.

Pressing the back button programmatically is a really crude workaround. So a solution where the url open event is actually canceled is much appreciated.

***Update:***

I had to remove `CanGoBack="True"` in the XAML and hard-code the property in `OnElementChanged` of my `WebViewRenderer`:

```
(Element as IWebViewController).CanGoBack = true;
```

Setting the `CanGoBack` property in XAML worked fine while the VS 2019 debugger was running attached but if running stand-alone, the app shut down immediately. Can be reproduced on a simple WebView without custom renderer:

```
ApplyPropertiesVisitor.SetPropertyValue (System.Object xamlelement, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XmlName propertyName, System.Object value, System.Object rootElement, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode node, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.HydrationContext context, System.Xml.IXmlLineInfo lineInfo)
ApplyPropertiesVisitor.Visit (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ValueNode node, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode parentNode)
ValueNode.Accept (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode parentNode)
ElementNode.Accept (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode parentNode)
ElementNode.Accept (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode parentNode)
RootNode.Accept (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode parentNode)
XamlLoader.Visit (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.RootNode rootnode, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.HydrationContext visitorContext, System.Boolean useDesignProperties)
XamlLoader.Load (System.Object view, System.String xaml, System.Reflection.Assembly rootAssembly, System.Boolean useDesignProperties)
XamlLoader.Load (System.Object view, System.String xaml, System.Boolean useDesignProperties)
XamlLoader.Load (System.Object view, System.Type callingType)
Extensions.LoadFromXaml[TXaml] (TXaml view, System.Type callingType)
WebPageCollabora.InitializeComponent ()
CloudplanMobileClient.WebPageCollabora..ctor (System.String url) [0x00031] in <6b79d357cd4641c5bd9a69278958d871>:0
WebPage+<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<OpenNewPage>b__0 ()
Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run ()
IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this)
(wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.27(intptr,intptr)
```

Comment: It seems that you have one solution to solve your problem?

Comment: Solution... It's rather a bad hack. And I already went into trouble with it today. There has to be a better way. I would have self-aswered my question, if I could live with it.

Comment: It does work in VS debugger but ``CanGoBack="True"`` lead to the app closing on startup if running stand-alone.

Comment: Hi @thomiel, can you please explain the issue a bit more for better understanding? Do you want to open the URL in browser and then automatically want to come back to webview (inside app)? Thanks.

Comment: @Aparupa Ghoshal I want to open only certain URLs in the WebView that belong to the web app and redirect other external links to Chrome.

Comment: WebView with/without VS/debug [permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=windows#permissions) ("some permissions ... are set by default by Visual Studio for Mac when in debug mode"): "Android – requires INTERNET only when displaying content from the network. Local content requires no special permissions."

Comment: @Benl The app has INTERNET permission set.

Comment: @Thomiel, Use Device.OpenUri(uri);  only for the external URls. You can using JS Bridge so that web can trigger that they are sending an external URL and you can open it using Device.OpenUri(uri); Rest of the URLs you can open directly in webview by using loadURL.

Comment: @Aparupa Ghostal The custom renderer already allows for hybrid JavaScript functions and I actually proposed this other workaround, but it was rejected in favor of the programmatically-press-back-button workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was wondering why the bug obviously [has been fixed in 2020](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/5460) and still I was experiencing the problem. I then noticed that the fix was applied only to `FormsWebViewClient` but not to the native `Xamarin.Android` class `WebViewClient`. I solved the issue just by deriving my web client used in my `HybridWebViewRenderer` from `FormsWebViewClient` instead of `WebViewClient` and modified the constructor a bit:

```
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

...

namespace MyApp.Droid
{    
    // note: class was derived from 'WebViewClient' before
    public class JavascriptWebViewClient : FormsWebViewClient  
    {
        HybridWebViewRenderer _renderer;
        string _javascript;

        // note: now also calling base class constructor with renderer as parameter
        public JavascriptWebViewClient(string javascript, HybridWebViewRenderer renderer) : base(renderer)
        {
            _javascript = javascript;
            _renderer = renderer ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("renderer");
        }

    ...

    }
}
```